# Angular JS: Chaining promises and the digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, promise

### **NOTE:** the fiddle uses an old version of Angular, and that it's not working any more because as of 1.2 the Angular template engine does not handle promises transparently.

I'm looking into chaining promises to populate my scope, and then having the scope automatically update the dom.

I'm running into problems with this though.. If I call "then" on an already resolved promise, it creates a new promise (that will call the success function asynchronously but almost immediately).  I think the problem is that we've already left the digest cycle by the time the success function is called, so the dom never updates.

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}! <br/>
    {{name2}}<br/>
    <button ng-click="go()">Clickme</button><br/>
    {{name3}}
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $q) {
    var data = $q.defer();    
    setTimeout(function() {$scope.$apply(data.resolve("Some Data"))}, 2000);
    var p = data.promise;

    $scope.name = p.then(angular.uppercase);
    $scope.name2 = p.then(function(x) { return "Hi "+x;});
    $scope.go = function() {
            $scope.name3 = p.then(function(x) { 
                // uncomment this to make it work:
                //$scope.$apply();
                return "Finally: "+x;
            });
    };
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QZM4d/

Is there some way to make this work without calling $apply every time I chain promises?

Comment: Why are you putting a promise in the `go()` function?

Comment: There is a promise there because I'm running code on the result of the original "p" promise.  I want the code to run correctly whether or not "p" has been resolved... hence we create a new promise from the old promise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **NOTE**: the fiddle uses an old version of Angular, and that it's not working any more because as of 1.2 the Angular template engine does not handle promises transparently.

To [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246907/215945) @pkozlowski.opensource:

> In AngularJS the results of promise resolution are propagated asynchronously, inside a $digest cycle. So, callbacks registered with then() will only be called upon entering a $digest cycle.

So, when the button is clicked, we are in a digest cycle.  then() creates a new promise, but the results of that then() will not be propagated until the *next* digest cycle, which never comes (because there is no $timeout, or $http, or DOM event to trigger one).  If you add another button with ng-click that does nothing, then click that, it will cause a digest cycle and you'll see the results:

```
<button ng-click="">Force digest by clicking me</button><br/>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/9CxC2/) that does that.

The fiddle also uses $timeout instead of setTimeout -- then $apply() isn't needed.

Hopefully it is clear when you need to use $apply.  Sometimes you do need to call it manually.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got my head around it now.  I ended up rewriting my question and code so many times that I got about 80% of the way there myself.  It kind of seems too bad that we have to manually force digest for resolving promises, but it could still be interesting to code that way.

Comment: I believe you can use $http or $q promises to allow an angular digest cycle to happen after the calls. I'm in search of the best way right now.

Comment: NOTE that the fiddle uses an old version of Angular, and that it's not working any more because as of 1.2 the Angular template engine does not handle promises transparently.

Comment: Adding a button that does nothing would work, but why clicking ng-click="go" twice doesn't trigger a digest cycle?

Comment: @axings, what is `go`?  If it is not a valid Angular expression, then a digest cycle probably won't run.

Comment: Sorry @MarkRajcok I meant ng-click="go()", according to this answer clicking a button would trigger a digest cycle, then why clicking <button ng-click="">Force digest by clicking me</button><br/> would indeed do so but clicking <button ng-click="go()">Clickme</button><br/> a second time does not?

Comment: >> kind of seems too bad that we have to manually force digest for resolving promises. Agree.