# AngularJS - why is $apply required to properly resolve a $q promise?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a small service in my angular app which will enable me to pick config parameters specified in global Javascript objects. I don't want to attempt accessing the global config object unless the document is ready (because I cannot guarantee the order in which script elements will be inserted in the HTML).

However, I can't understand why I need the call to `$apply` for the resolution to actually propagate to the `then` callback.

```
myModule.service('GlobalConfigService', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        def.resolve(MyConfig.val);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    def.promise.then(function () {
        console.log('I am called only when $apply() is called. Why?');
    });

    return def.promise;
}]);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In AngularJS the results of resolve() are propagated asynchronously, inside a $digest cycle, not immediately.  This means that callbacks registered with then() will only be called (later) when a digest cycle occurs.

In your code, nothing is causing Angular to enter a digest cycle, so the then() callback is never called.  Calling $apply() is one way to cause a digest cycle to run.  Another way: add a button with ng-click that does nothing, then click that, it will cause a digest cycle and you should see the results:

```
<button ng-click="">Force digest by clicking me</button>
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14657974/215945