# AngularJs unit test - mocked promise not executing "then"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, promise

We're unit testing our controllers. We've successfully mocked the call to our REST service layer and verified that it is indeed being called with the given data. Now however we'd like to test that in our controller the execution of the `then` promise changes the `location.path`:

controller:

```
(function () {

    app.controller('registerController', ['$scope', '$location', '$ourRestWrapper', function ($scope, $location, $ourRestWrapper) {

    $scope.submitReg = function(){
        // test will execute this
        var promise = $ourRestWrapper.post('user/registration', $scope.register);

        promise.then(function(response) {    
                console.log("success!"); // test never hits here           
                $location.path("/");
        },
            function(error) {
                console.log("error!"); // test never hits here
                $location.path("/error");
            }
        );
    };
```

`$ourRestWrapper.post(url,data)` just wraps `Restangular.all(url).post(data)`..

Our Test:

```
(function () {

    describe("controller: registerController", function() {

        var scope, location, restMock, controller, q, deferred;

        beforeEach(module("ourModule"));

        beforeEach(function() {
            restMock = {
                post: function(url, model) {
                    console.log("deferring...");
                    deferred = q.defer();    
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
        });

        // init controller for test
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $ourRestWrapper, $location, $q){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            location = $location;
            q = $q;

            controller = $controller('registerController', {
                $scope: scope, $location: location, $ourRestWrapper: restMock});
        }));

    it('should call REST layer with registration request', function() {
        scope.register = {data:'test'};

        spyOn(restMock, 'post').andCallThrough();

        scope.submitReg();

        deferred.resolve();

        // successfull
        expect(restMock.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('user/registration',scope.register);
        expect(restMock.post.calls.length).toEqual(1);
        // fail: Expected '' to be '/'.
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/');
    });
```

In our console we see "deferring..." and the first two expectations succeed. Why will it not call the `then` block (i.e. set the location)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cache the `$rootscope` object when you get it from the injector and call `$rootScope.$apply()` immediately after `deferred.resolve()`.

Comment: Wow! Can anyone share why this resolves the issue? I have been fighting this all day.

Comment: I could thank you more for your helpful answer. This "not executing `then`" issue has kept me up in wee hour. Did a real quick googling and found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746314/angularjs-why-is-apply-required-to-properly-resolve-a-q-promise

> In short, in unit testing the `$digest` cycle is not being called, so calling `$rootScope.$apply()` forces the digest cycle to run