# How do I get then on $http to resolve on an Karma AngularJS automated test so that it passes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Here's a simplified version of my code:

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlX8oV2bMtzXrxtwGX8q?p=preview

```
angular.module('test', []).factory('test', function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.load = function () {
        return $http.get('api/test');
    };

    return service;
})

describe('test', function () {
    var test;
    var $httpBackend;
    var $q;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('test'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_test_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {
        test = _test_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should be defined', function (done) {
        var expected = 123;
        $httpBackend.whenGET('api/test').respond(expected);
        var promise = test.load();

        promise.then(function (result) {
            expect(result.data).toBe(expected);
            done();
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
});
```

I'm already calling `$rootScope.$apply()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916348/angularjs-unit-test-mocked-promise-not-executing-then) suggests.

The test runner is timing out.  That means `done()` is never getting called.  That means the function passed into `then` is never getting called.  How do I get that function called?  I would expect triggering a digest cycle to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `respond` should be the status code.

`$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();` was giving an error, so I took that out.

```
angular.module('test', []).factory('test', function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.load = function () {
        return $http.get('api/test');
    };

    return service;
})

describe('test', function () {
    var test;
    var $httpBackend;
    var $q;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('test'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_test_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {
        test = _test_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should be defined', function (done) {
        var expected = 123;
        $httpBackend.whenGET('api/test').respond(200, expected);
        var promise = test.load();

        promise.then(function (result) {
            expect(result.data).toBe(expected);
            done();
            console.log('here');
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```