# My AngularJS model only updates when my button is clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a select list box, and the I have a button. Based on the button `selectId`, I have to filter the model which showing in the select list box.

The problem here is that the model only updates when I click this button twice. I have a filter function in `GetFormsClicked` which have logic regarding this.

My Angular controller is the following:

```js
(function() {
  var controllerId = 'GroupsController';

  ig.app.controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$compile', 'fileRvwQuestSvc', 'DataSvc',
    function($scope, $log, $http, $compile, fileRvwQuestSvc, DataSvc) {

      $scope.FrequencyMap = {
        1: "Annual",
        2: "Monthly",
        3: "Half Year"
      };

      $scope.FormMap = {
        1: "CMSMISC",
        2: "CMSFPEA",
        3: "CMSPIID",
        5: "CMSMSR",
        7: "CMSCOI"
      }

      $scope.GetAllGroupForms = function(Id) {
        var url = '/GroupForm/Details/' + Id;
        $scope.loading = true;
        DataSvc.getAjaxData(url)
          .then(function(data) {
            //success        
            $scope.GroupForm = data.data;
            $scope.GroupFormBack = data.data;
            $scope.loading = false;
          }, function(httpStatus) {
            //failed
            $scope.hasErrors = true;
            if (httpStatus === 404) {
              $scope.errorMessage = "Couldn't retrieve Users Info";
            } else {
              $scope.errorMessage = 'The system could not process your request, please try again or contact the system administrator.';
            }
            $log.warn(httpStatus);
            $scope.loading = false;
          });
      };


      $scope.availableFormsTestOriginal = [

        {
          "Id": null,
          "GroupId": null,
          "FormId": 1,
          "SortOrder": null,
          "Frequency": 1,
          "IsCollapsed": false,
          "IsDeleted": false
        },
        {
          "Id": null,
          "GroupId": null,
          "FormId": 2,
          "SortOrder": null,
          "Frequency": 1,
          "IsCollapsed": false,
          "IsDeleted": false
        },
        {
          "Id": null,
          "GroupId": null,
          "FormId": 3,
          "SortOrder": null,
          "Frequency": 1,
          "IsCollapsed": false,
          "IsDeleted": false
        }

      ]


      var AddGroupForm = function() {

        $scope.loading = true;
        var url = '/GroupForm/Create/';
        DataSvc.AddFormData(url, $scope.GroupForm)
          .then(function(data) {
            //success
            $scope.loading = false;
            //$scope.successMessage = "Form Saved Successfully";
            $scope.successMessage = "GroupForm Updated Successfully";
          }, function(httpStatus) {
            //failed
            $scope.hasErrors = true;
            if (httpStatus === 404) {
              $scope.errorMessage = "Couldn't retrieve Users Info";
            } else {
              $scope.errorMessage = 'The system could not process your request, please try again or contact the system administrator.';
            }
            $log.warn(httpStatus);
            $scope.loading = false;
          });
      }

      $scope.filterailableforms = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.availableFormsTest.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < $scope.GroupForm.length; j++) {
            if ($scope.availableFormsTest[i].FormId === $scope.GroupForm[j].FormId && $scope.availableFormsTest[i].Frequency === $scope.GroupForm[j].Frequency) {
              $scope.availableFormsTest.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        }

      }


      activate();

      $scope.GetFormsClicked = function(selectid) {
        $scope.availableFormsTest = angular.copy($scope.availableFormsTestOriginal);
        $scope.GetAllGroupForms(selectid);
        $scope.updateavailableforms(selectid);
        $scope.filterailableforms();
      }

      function activate() {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.GetAllGroup();

      }


    }
  ]);
})();
```

My view code is as follows:

```html
<button ng-click="GetFormsClicked(selectedId)">Select Group <span style="color:black"></span></button>` <select size="5" multiple ng-model="available" ng-options="x as FormMap[x.FormId]+' --- '+FrequencyMap[x.Frequency] for x in availableFormsTest" style="width: 400px"></select>
```

My dataser code:

```
ig.app.factory('DataSvc', [
'$http', '$q', '$log',
function ($http, $q, $log) {
    return {
        getAjaxData: function (CtrlUrl) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var rnd = ((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: CtrlUrl + "/?r=" + rnd
            })
            .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
            },
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        AddFormData: function (CtrlUrl, model) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(CtrlUrl, model).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
            },function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        UpdateFormData: function (CtrlUrl, model) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(CtrlUrl, model).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
        },function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Someone Please help with this

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to the use of `ng-model="variable"`.

The rule is "always have a dot in your ng-model", you should have a `ng-model="obj.variable"` with the correct obj.

The reason is that each directive with `scope:true` inherits the parent scope, and the "variable" you are editing isn't copied back to the parent.

The problem is due to the fact that the strings are copied by value. 
By using an object, all the scope will reference the same variable.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a example how to do the change? What do you mean correct obj?  Should I use obj.available?

Comment: I tried this approach. But still not working for me.

Comment: Ah ! Do your ajax call is written with jquery or $http ? If jquery, you need To use scope. $apply To force the update.

Comment: It is $http. Thanks

Comment: Could we have the code of your service ? There is a callback not wrapped in scope.$apply i'm sure

Comment: Hey,@Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant  I just updated the service code

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746314/angularjs-why-is-apply-required-to-properly-resolve-a-q-promise it seems you need to call scope.$apply ;)

Comment: Thanks. Where should I call scope.$apply. I tried to called after filter  function, but it is not working

Comment: after your `deferred.resolve` like in the post i sent you