# AngularJS directive not updating view as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I am using a directive for form-validation-as-you-type. An http request is made for every change of the username field. I can see in my console that the requests happen, but the view isn't updated with the "unique" error message until a blur event occurs for the field.

However, as soon as the username is changed from a duplicate to a unique one, the error message disappears instantly. No blur is needed going in this direction (hide error message), only in the other (display error message)...

Why is that?

======= Directive =========

```
myDirs.directive('ensureUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {  if (scope.registered) {return true};
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://webservice.buddyplatform.com/v1/UserAccount_Profile_CheckUserName',
                params: {
                    UserNameToVerify: ele.val(),
                    BuddyApplicationName:'xxx',
                    BuddyApplicationPassword:'yyy'
                }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
                    c.$setValidity('unique', (data==='UserNameAvailble'));
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
                    c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                });
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

=========== HTML ===============

```
<label>Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="form.username" 
           ng-minlength=5 ng-maxlength=20 ensure-unique="username" required/>
    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.$dirty && myForm.username.$invalid">
        <small class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.$error.required">Please input a username</small>
        <small class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.$error.minlength">Your username is required to be at least 5 characters</small>
        <small class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.$error.maxlength">Your username cannot be longer than 20 characters</small>
        <small class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.$error.unique">That username is taken, please try another</small>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The digest cycle is tricky, but as I understand it, success is inside a digest cycle, there is no new digest cycle after. So setting the validity doesn't mean there will be another digest. There are a few ways to get around this. The easiest way is to use `$timeout` service. To do that, inject `$timeout` into your directive then change the code like so:

`$timeout(function(){c.$setValidity('unique', (data==='UserNameAvailble'));});`

You can also do this with an $apply or by manually triggering a $digest. But both of those methods can trigger an error if you're out of phase. $timeout is not as fast because it ALWAYS triggers another digest, even if one isn't needed. There are a ton of questions related to digests, cycles, etc.  This one is particularly relavent: [Angular JS: Chaining promises and the digest cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657680/angular-js-chaining-promises-and-the-digest-cycle)

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but to my surprise, the problem remains.