# Instant redirection gives error in console

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {

    // TypeError: Cannot read property '$destroy' of null
    $state.go('some.page'); 

    // No Error
    $timeout(function () {
        $state.go('some.page'); 
    }, 500);
});
```

500ms delay prevent from error.

Why instant page change gives "Cannot read property '$destroy' of null" error?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought on this was wondering where the best place to use $state.go is. I have always used it in the controller and didn't even know you could do it in the service... But at the end of the day, it shouldn't matter. So I did some googling on it and found this issue on github! It seems to have the same problem that was solved with a timeout but just by moving the $state.go into the controller fixes it as well.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/403

Hope it this helps!

Edit: Here is another stackoverflow question about something similar

[AngularJS behaving strangely when there's a nested relationship of promises in services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755383/angularjs-behaving-strangely-when-theres-a-nested-relationship-of-promises-in-s)