# Delayed $scope updates in promise `.then` method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I'm using angularJS and I do this:

```
xxx.then(function (response) {
    $scope.x = response.x;
    $scope.y = response.y;
}, function (error) {}
);
```

The response come from server not instantantly. Then when the response come, I want than the scope update my value, but it does that just when I click in some button other so.

In my html I receive the informations so:

```
<p>{{x}}</p>
<p>{{y}}</p>
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Share some more code of how you are making this request or create a plunkr.

Comment: If I do a console.log($scope.x) next to $scope.y = response.y; I obtain the good value, but it don't actualize my html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with the digest cycle, try doing `$scope.$apply()` like below :

```
    xxx.then(function (response) {
     $scope.x = response.x;
     $scope.y = response.y;
     $scope.$apply();
    }, function (error) {});
```

> In AngularJS the results of promise resolution are propagated
>   asynchronously, inside a $digest cycle. So, callbacks registered with
>   then() will only be called upon entering a $digest cycle.

The results of your promise will not be propagated until the next digest cycle. As there is nothing else in your code that triggers the digest cycle, changes are not getting applied immediately. But, when you click on a button , it triggers the digest cycle, due to which the changes are getting applied

Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657680/angular-js-chaining-promises-and-the-digest-cycle/14657974#14657974) for a clear explanation about this.

Comment: If the digest cycle is already in progress, doing `$scope.$apply` again will throw an error in console . Please check that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A `.then` method may fail to update the DOM if the promise comes from a source other than the $q service. Use `$q.when` to convert the external promise to a $q service promise:

```
//xxx.then(function (response) {
$q.when(xxx).then(function (data) {
    $scope.x = data.x;
    $scope.y = data.y;
}, function (error) {
    throw error;
});
```

The $q service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and the $q service `.then` method will automatically invoke the framework digest cycle to update the DOM.

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)