# Angular.js promise not resolving when unit testing service with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test an Angular.js service, and need to set an expect on a promise returned from a Mock service (using Jasmine). I am using the karma unit testing framework. The relevant code snippet is below:

```
// I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of a $scope.$digest here. 
var loginStatusPromise = FacebookService.getFacebookToken();
loginStatusPromise.then(function(token) {
    expect(false).toBeTruthy(); // If this test passes, there is something going wrong!
    expect(token).not.toBeNull(); // The token should be ValidToken
    expect(token).toBe('ValidToken');
});
```

The complete unit test code can be seen [here](https://github.com/bradleyscott/yieldtome/blob/master/Web/test/unit/services/facebookServiceSpec.js).

The problem is the promise.then statement never fires when karma is executing. Hence, none of my expect statements are executed. 
In my controller tests, I use $scope.$digest() to resolve the promises, but I am not clear on how to do this in a service test. As I thought there was no notion of 'scope' in a service test.

Do I have the wrong end of the stick here? Do I need to injecct $rootScope into my service test and then use $digest? Or, is there another way?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Yes, see below. Calling $rootScope.$digest() doesn't seem to work either. Something else is at play here. Link to updated code is shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [ngFacebook/ngModule](https://github.com/GoDisco/ngFacebook) a quick note before the solution/ideas is that this project does not have unit tests ! Are you sure you want to use this project ?

I did a quick scan of your Unit Tests on Github and found following missing:-

**1) Module initialization**. 
ngFacebook needs that or you need to initialize your module that does the same thing.

```
beforeEach(module('ngFacebook'));
```

OR

```
beforeEach(module('yieldtome'));
```

**2) Seriously consider mocking ngFacebook module**

At unit level tests you are testing your code within a mocked bubble where outside interfaces are stubbed out.

Otherwise) Try adding calling the API as below:-

```
 $rootScope.$apply(function() {
     this.FacebookService.getFacebookToken().then(function(){
        //your expect code here
     });
    });
 $httpBackend.flush();//mock any anticipated outgoing requests as per [$httpBackend][2]
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem and resolved it by simply putting a 
`$rootScope.$apply()` at the end of my test

Your FacebookService might be the issue, as suggested by @mpm. Are you sure it doesn't have any http calls happening inside of that `Facebook` dependency which wouldn't be occurring during unit testing? Are you certain that `resolve` has been called on the deferred yet?

Comment: Putting `$rootScope.$apply()` right after `promise.resolved()` helped me in a similar case. The AngularJS promises seem to fire only in the next iteration of the `$digest` loop, which may not be automatically triggered in such a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach(function(){
   var self=this;
    inject(function($rootScope,Facebook){
        self.$rootScope=$rootScope;
        self.Facebook=Facebook;
    });
})

it('resolves unless sourcecode broken',function(done){
    // I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of a $scope.$digest here. 
    var loginStatusPromise = this.FacebookService.getFacebookToken();
    loginStatusPromise.then(function(token) {
        expect(token).toBe('ValidToken');
        done();
    });
    $rootscope.$apply();

});
```

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work either. Then function not called, done not hit.

Comment: If it's broken- then it is broken in such a way that it works in the real app, but breaks only when running as a unit test / in karma. The FacebookService code can be seen at [here](https://github.com/bradleyscott/yieldtome/blob/master/Web/app/js/services/facebookService.js) and you can browse the rest of the repo there too if there are other files you want to look at

Comment: This whole thing about $rootScope is kind of wrong (regardless of if it works or not). A unit test for a service shouldn't know ANYTHING about a controller scope. The fact that $q somehow interacts with $rootScope can't possibly be valid separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answers that a service should have nothing to do with `$rootScope`.

In my case had a `$q` promise, that used a second service internally resolving to a promise as well. No way to resolve the external one, unless I added `$rootScope.$digest()` into my service code (not the test)...

I ended-up writing this quick shim for `$q` to use in my tests, but be careful, as it's just an example and not a complete `$q` implementation.

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('$q', {
    defer: function() {
      var _resolve, _reject;
      return {
        promise: {
          then: function (resolve, reject) {
            _resolve = resolve;
            _reject = reject;
          }
        },
        resolve: function (data) {
          window.setTimeout(_resolve, 0, data);
        },
        reject: function (data) {
          window.setTimeout(_reject, 0, data);
        }
      };
    }
  });
}));
```

Hope it will be useful to someone, or if you have any feedback.

Thanks.