# Testing multiple promises with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test the createGrant function and I have mocked both the getGrant and getGroup functions; however, I am still getting errors because from my test the showModal is not getting fired.

Both the getGroup and getGrant returns a promise each and both promises has to resolve before the showModal gets called.

Thanks in advance for  any help.

-dj

```
$scope.createGrant = function(group) {
function showModal() {
  $scope.activeGrant = {};
  $scope.activeGroup = group;

  myModal({
    template: 'templates/edit-grant.tpl.html',
    scope: $scope,
    modalClass: 'edit-grant-modal'
  });
}

var msg;
$q.all([grantService.getGrant(group.id).then(function(grantResponse) {
    if (grantResponse) {
      msg = {
        message: '....',
        classes: ['alert-danger']
      };
    }
  }), 
  subscriberGroupService.getGroup(group).then(function(grpResponse) {
    $scope.grpName =  grpResponse.name
  }, function() {
    msg = {
      message: '....',
      classes: ['alert-danger']
    };
  }
)]).then(function(values) {     
  if (_.isUndefined(msg)) {
      showModal();
  }else{
     notify(msg);
  }
 });
```

};

Error:

`Expected undefined to equal {  }.
    Error: Expected undefined to equal {  }.
        at .<anonymous> (/....unit.spec.js:127:32)
    Expected undefined to equal { id : 7 }.
    Error: Expected undefined to equal { id : 7 }.
        at .<anonymous> (/....unit.spec.js:128:32)
    Expected spy myModalMock to have been called.
    Error: Expected spy myModalMock to have been called.
        at .<anonymous> (/....unit.spec.js:129:27)`

Comment: I believe you need to call $scope.$apply(); to force angular's digest cycle which will resolve the promises.
Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513249/angular-js-promise-not-resolving-when-unit-testing-service-with-karma

Comment: How are you mocking the getGroup and getGrant functions? do the mocks return promises? 
The following should work:
`spyOn(grantService, 'getGrant').and.returnValue($q.when())`;
`scope.createGrant()`;
`scope.$apply()`;

Comment: Some more info, I added the get group call to the existing code.  Before adding the getGroup, the test was working file.  I tried to add the scope.$apply but that causes other problems.